# Applications Configuration management tools

Tags: java, configuration, osgi, puppet

I'm looking for a tool for managing configuration of applications. I've found that `OSGi` implementations provide a `Config Admin service` that may be used with `Apache Karaf` + `Apache Cellar`. So, there is a master node and some client nodes that retrieve configuration from the master node. I've also looked at `Puppet` which provide much more features.

But, I don't know if it fits well for OSGi based applications, and if yes, if it provides the same functionality as the Config Admin service?

Answer (score 0):

Config Admin is a (small) API to manage configurations (dynamically) *inside* an OSGi framework. It is tightly integrated with the OSGi lifecycle, service, and bundle model. It is also a primary aspect of Declarative Services (DS) where it can control the binding and life cycle of DS components in detail.

Puppet is a generic (and HUGE) model to manage OS instances.

So in general they would not be comparable. If you're looking to control a remote OS, configuring daemons, processes, /etc, then Puppet is likely the solution for you. However, if you have a Java application that needs to be remotely managed then OSGi Configuration Admin + a framework might be the way to go. This would not have to be restricted to just the Java process. The [bndtools.rt packager](https://github.com/bndtools/bndtools-rt/tree/master/org.bndtools.rt.packager) shows how you can also package native processes in a bundle and then use OSGi remote management to control their life cycle and configuration.

So it all depends on what you want ...